# Closing a nested text file, and also cutting lines from nested text file

Tags: python, file, beautifulsoup

```
for h3 in soup.find_all('a'):

    print((str(h3.text)),file=open("demo.txt", "a"))
```

Up above is my line of code for scraping a website. I am using beautiful soup and selenium to scrape the website. The first line it says for all "a" tags soup find all. Then print the text of those a tags and print it in the file demo.txt.

For some reason I have to put "a" ,append, for the whole text to be printed out. With "w" it only prints one line. I am looking for a way to close the demo.txt file so that it does constantly keep appending to the same file.

It would also be helpful in learning how to cut certain lines from the text file. Ie the text file will probably be 750-1000 lines so a command to cut (2-5, 94-100) would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will print one line because every time when he found what u say to search will open that file and will write it. Computer do not know the word "delete" when we talk about words on files =]] So for him, no mater what is on this file (and if that file will not exist will create it) will start from beginning and will write it again. for that reason **a** is working for you.

```py
try:
    with open(file="demo.txt", mode="w", encoding="utf-8") as file:

        for h3 in soup.find_all('a'):
            file.write(str(h3.text))
finally:
    file.close()
```

And for that deleting lines I thing u do not want some information's on it, so check what do u not want and make another if statement inside.

```py
...
        for h3 in soup.find_all('a'):
            if stringA in h3.text or stringB in h3.text:
                pass
            else:
                file.write(str(h3.text))
...
```